# How to sort a character vector that has numbers in it

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame that I am trying to sort by character's that contain numbers in it.

The column looks like this (Team1, Team2, Team3, Team4, Team5,....Team10) and when I sort it will sort it as (Team1, Team10, Team2 ....). I am using this with hundreds of different terms in that column so is there a way that you can sort the column so it sees the Team2 as an earlier value than Team3?

Comment: You can use `df1$col1 <- gtools::mixedsort(df1$col1)`

Comment: Alternatively, you could extract the team number and use that to sort (e. g. `df %>% mutate(team_no = str_extract(col1, "\\d+")) %>% arrange(team_no)`)

Answer (score 1):

Using base R:

```
set.seed(357)
xy <- paste("Team", sample(1:10), sep = "")
```

Sorting "the dumb way".

```
xy.sort <- sort(xy)
xy.sort

[1] "Team1"  "Team10" "Team2"  "Team3"  "Team4"  "Team5"  "Team6"  "Team7"  "Team8"  "Team9"
```

If you extract the number and convert them to numeric, you can use them to order the original data.frame.

```
get.nums <- gsub("^Team(\\d+)$", replacement = "\\1", x = xy)
xy[order(as.numeric(get.nums))]

[1] "Team1"  "Team2"  "Team3"  "Team4"  "Team5"  "Team6"  "Team7"  "Team8"  "Team9"  "Team10"
```

Comment: Definitely works for this example, but that depends on uniformity in the "alpha" part of the input vector... Hello, BTW :-)

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 the entire world is edge case! :) Hello.